# Google Maps API v3: Radius parameter doesn't seem to limit autocomplete results

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm trying to limit autocomplete results to a city by setting a country through `componentRestrictions` and a radius through `radius`, as explained here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

The country limitation works, not the radius unfortunately (it should limit addresses within 500 meters, in this case)! Can you help me..?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&amp;sensor=false&amp;region=it&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.88994,12.51383);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom:16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: myLatlng,
        styles: [
            {
                featureType: "poi.business",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                        { visibility: "off" }
                ]
            }
        ]
      }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));


    var input = document.getElementById('start');
var options = {
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'it'},
radius: '500',
};
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'My Marker'
    });





    }



    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        if (start.indexOf("Roma") === -1) {
            start += ", Roma";
        }
          var end = "Via Tiburtina 500, Roma";
          var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
          };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

    <form onsubmit="calcRoute(); return false">
        <input type="text" id="start" name="start" placeholder="Indirizzo di partenza" style="margin-left:5px;width:200px">
        <input type="submit" value="Vai">
    </form>


        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 927px; margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px; height: 300px; position: relative;"></div>
        <div id="directions-panel"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found this but the example provided doesn't seem to restrict entries to map area.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=fr#changing_the_search_area

Comment: In this example "radius" parameter is used:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search?hl=fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `radius`-option for a places.Autocomplete , only a [`bounds`-option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#AutocompleteOptions) to restrict the area

Comment: Is there a sort of latlngbounds definer? How can I calculate the coordinates of the rectangle? :)

Comment: you may create a circle by the given LatLng and radius and use the method getBounds() of the circle to retrieve the bounds.

Comment: I tried to add `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(49.00, -13.00), new google.maps.LatLng(60.00, 3.00));` but autocomplete stopped working.. those coords should be UK. Test here: http://ffio.it/test_bounds.html

Comment: you must move the call of `autocomplete.setBounds()` behind the creation of the autocomplete.

Comment: Ok, now the map is loaded but the bounds aren't respected (can check at same link). If I type "A" the first suggestions are "Australia, "Austria"...

Comment: your bounds are not respected because you call `autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);` in the next line, what will override the restriction to `bounds`. When you remove this line you will still get e.g. Australia when you type a single A(you also get it when you try it with the google-demos), but when you type more you get results restricted to `bounds`